# Dynamic VueRouter imports for named Views using Promisses

Tags: vue.js, promise, es6-promise, vue-router

I'm trying to dynamically load my components views for Vue-Router. The import statement used is a promise, but it is always returning a promise instead of the actual value as the returned value even when i chain ".then" just incase the promise returns another promise.  What i'm I doing wrong please?

```
generatedRoute['component'] = {
                filter_menu_view: import(`../../${this._filter_menu_view_path}.vue`).then((resolve) => resolve),
                action_page_view: action_page_view.then((resolve) => {
                    return resolve
                }).then((resolve2) => {
                    console.log(resolve2);
                    return resolve2
                }),
            }
```

Basically, I'm try to achieve this https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/named-views.html but lazy load the views using import. Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because `then` also returns promise.

You code looks strange so its hard to tell what you are trying to do but generally when using dynamic imports Vue expects [a function returning promise](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-dynamic-async.html#Async-Components)

So change

```js
filter_menu_view: import(`../../${this._filter_menu_view_path}.vue`).then((resolve) => resolve)
```

for

```js
filter_menu_view: () => import(`../../${this._filter_menu_view_path}.vue`)
```

...you are creating a function which returns a promise (of component). Vue will call the function when component is needed and wait for promise to resolve to use the component returned by `import`

### Edit

Oh yeah, and if your are trying to use named views, the key is `components`, not `component`

Comment: Thanks Levy, I have edited the question for clarity. Yes, it looks like ```then``` returns a promise. But then i had a chain of two  ```then```'s and the latter's return was still a promise.

Comment: No matter how many `then`'s you will chain, result will be always a promise....

Comment: Works!! thank you levy. i still don't get how that works tho because it returns some promise i'm expected to resolve.. need to read more i guess. thanks.